# Lazy-evaluation in a initializer with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, lazy-evaluation

I have a Settings class on a Rails app with several columns updateable by an admin user in the backend, f.i. support_email, so I want to re-evaluate this column every time the app sends an email after a new user sign up.

I tried with a stubby lambda in the Devise initializer, like scopes in classes:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # Omitted config
  config.mailer_sender = -> { "AppName <#{Settings.get(:support_email)}>" }
  # Omitted config
end
```

but it doesn't work because it returns a Proc object.

I tried with **.call** directly in the stubby lambda, although I don't know if it's a good practice:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # Omitted config
  config.mailer_sender = -> { "AppName <#{Settings.get(:support_email)}>" }.call
  # Omitted config
end
```

This approach doesn't work because I receive the same value that I received after first evaluation.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I think you will have to monkeypatch devise to achieve that.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?